# Post tension slab tendons intersections

Tags: foundation, slab, new-home

I ordered pre-pour inspection for the house we are building and I've got this report. They say tendons should not overlap at intersections. I'm concerned that it's like that by design. Gonna ask about it but wanna see if anyone could answer if that's correct installation.

Update. The builder's response: It should not be addressed.
Not required per post tension specs. The cables in the beams are ran so you will see a weave with the cables. All is installed correct per Engineer's requirements

[image]

Comment: Is this in Texas or close by?  Just wondering since youtube vid was about this type a few weeks ago.

Comment: Have you asked the company doing the job what they recommend?  Is it done according to the approved plan?  Are there notes on the plan as to tendon placement?

Comment: yes it is in Texas. @crip659 could you share a video?

Comment: I've asked the company who does it. they said: Not required per post tension specs. The cables in the beams are ran so you will see a weave with the cables. Aii is installed correct per Engineer's requirements.

Comment: Sorry I can't.  It was about why Texas does not dig/use basements, so that might help finding it.  It was just something I saw browsing.  It used the same type of pads, which is why I recognized it, do not think they went into much detail of designing/building, more of the why.

Comment: I suggest you take the engineers report/ requirements to the regulation authorities and show them that it is done according to plan.  If they say, no. Go back to the engineer and ask why their plan will not pass the local code.  It really sounds like an inspector know just enough to be dangerous here.

Comment: I expect that the building department will demand a letter from the engineer, and the builder will huff and puff and then rearrange the tendons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why they used the word "overlap." They're complaining about a strand going over one perpendicular strand and then under the next. The pattern kinda kinks the strand at the alternating intersections. When the strands are tightened, the over/under pattern will introduce some extra friction, reducing the tendon tensions. If there's only one kink per tendon, then I wouldn't worry about it. 10 kinks in a single tendon? That's too much for me unless I can confirm that it's okay by rational analysis.

For post-tensioning design, there's wobble friction and curvature friction. Wobble friction captures tension loss due to "minor" deviations from the designed profile. Curvature friction captures the tension loss due to designed curves. Was the wobble friction modeled by the designer similar to the curvature friction for your goofy installation? I don't know.

The [2021 IBC 1808.6.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2021P2/chapter-18-soils-and-foundations#IBC2021P2_Ch18_Sec1808.6.2) cites the Post Tension Institute as an authority for the design of post-tensioned slabs, so putzing around their website I found Section 3.1 from [Prestress Losses in Post-Tensioned Structures](https://www.post-tensioning.org/Portals/13/Files/Pdfs/Education/Technote10.pdf). For wobble friction it specs a frictional coefficient of 0.00075/ft, and for curvature friction it specs a frictional coefficient of 0.22/radian:

P<sub>x</sub> = P<sub>j</sub>e<sup>-[(0.00075/ft)x + (0.22/radian)α]</sup>.

For wobble, x is easy. It's 4ft. For α I need a maximum slope (it gets multiplied by 2 to account for a mirror image of the slope on the other side of the cable intersection). The beam "shape function" that's typically named N<sub>3</sub> in structural analysis texts captures the curve of one of your over/under cables. Assuming a 1/2" diameter cable, one cable end is 1" higher than the other, so the shape is y(x) = (1")(1/(48")<sup>3</sup>)(-2x<sup>3</sup>+3x<sup>2</sup>(48")). Taking the derivative and evaluating at x = (48")/2 = 24" will provide the maximum slope,

y'(x) = (1")(1/(48")<sup>3</sup>)(-6x<sup>2</sup>+6x(48")) => y'(24") = 0.031 radians.

Comparing the wobble term (0.00075/ft)x = (0.00075/ft)(4ft) = 0.0030 to the curvature term (0.22/radian)(0.031radian)(2) = 0.014, e<sup>-0.0030</sup> = 99.7% and e<sup>-0.014</sup> = 98.6%. Clearly the wobble friction spec anticipates far less variation than your construction pattern. For one over/under in an entire tendon, I wouldn't worry about it. For 10 over/under instances in a single tendon, though, that 98.6% compounds down to (0.986)<sup>10</sup> = 87.8%, whereas 40 ft of wobble only loses 3.0% to drop down to 97.0%.

Comment: even for 10 over/under 97% still sounds quite good, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Rainmaker, for 10 over/under, the 98.6% compounds down to 87.8%. The 97.0% is based on 40 ft length under the wobble spec, not your as-built.